# enum in codebehind file `some.aspx.cs` not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have `website project`.
Inside of that I have, 
`App_Code` **folder**
            `CSharp` **folder** 
                      `Models.cs` class file
                      `CommonFunctions.cs` class file
***Models.cs***

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Models
/// </summary>
public class Models
{
    public Models()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
}
public enum InsuranceType { firstType, secondType}
```

Now I can access this enum in `CommonFunctions.cs` file like `InsuranceType.firstType`.

But I can't access this enum in `default.aspxs.cs` page.

**Why?** Or **what is missing?**

Comment: What are the namespace of the classes? Are you missing a `using` directive?

Comment: I just have `Models.cs` class file. I let VS to resolve it. But didn't get any help.

Comment: So what is the namespace? You didn't answer my question.

Comment: How and from where do I get it?

Comment: It should be in your code file.

Comment: look at `Models.cs` again. I have updated question.

Comment: Try to put a namespace around the class and see if you can reference that from your code behind files.

Answer (score 1):

Define namespace for in both **.CS** files and try to build again.